# how to create modules in laravel 5 or hmvc in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing **hmvc in laravel 5**.But didnt find usefully step and code ,there will be short description each internet solution ,but i am beginner in laravel 5

I am using below library by following this link: 
https://github.com/teepluss/laravel-hmvc

I am writing this code in route :

```
hmvc::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

but getting error:

**HmvcNotFoundHttpException in Hmvc.php line 133: Request Not Found.**

**Call to undefined method Teepluss\Hmvc\Hmvc::get().**

Answer (score 1):

Check your provider and aliases.

```
'providers' => array(

'Teepluss\Hmvc\HmvcServiceProvider'

)



'aliases' => [

'HMVC' => 'Teepluss\Hmvc\Facades\HMVC',

]
```

and run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

at route:

```
HMVC::get('hello-world');
```